# android webview can not open a url but browser of mobile can open it

Tags: android, url, webview

I can not load url of

http://s.click.taobao.com/t?e=zGU34CA7K%2BPkqB07S4%2FK0CITy7klxn%2F7bvn0ayzZySqVssDl3gbF6MnYRKHHUdcB3aJvSsy9BYnoGzvR6KxV8lKdtva8B8jzzIkjsGKfqPZV6Xsb0GvL9dwnAjjjJo%2FBmPilqOqPAb4WJjL3C5sjoaZ1gW%2FGA%2B8RO92rSapI&pid=mm_23353219_0_0&spm=2014.21047752.2.0

but I can open "http://www.google.com" with the same code.

and the browser of mobile can open it.

need help.

thank you.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to load the URL in the WebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ff00ff">
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView1"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

class:

```
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb.loadUrl("http://ursite/");
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add

`wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

before loading the URL

Answer (score 0):

Post the code you are using to open the WebView.

Incidentally, have you added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

to your application manifest?

Answer (score 0):

WebView in xml:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />
```

in class:

Call your website link in a string and call like this

```
    WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.loadUrl(your string);
```

I tried it and it's working.....